# Create a list in Python with Spanish synonyms from Spanish word

Tags: python

Say that I have a word in Spanish, 'contador', for which I want to obtain a finite set of synonyms '['contable','tesorero','medidor',...]'.

I am aware that I can obtain synonyms from Wordnet Synsets in Python, but only for words in English.

My question is: how can I generate the desired list of synonyms with Python?

Comment: What you're basically asking for is a library like Wordnet but for Spanish. That's not a bad question, but unfortunately SO is not a good place to ask for library recommendations. You may want to try either the resources in the Community section at python.org (probably python-list mailing list or #python IRC) or some similar place that's more specific to Spanish-language or international Python programming (I don't know of one, but I'm sure they exist).

Comment: You can extend wordnet for use with other languages by installing corpora from the [open multilingual wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/index.html) using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)

Comment: @abarnert thanks for letting me know of the Python Community sections. I was certainly not aware of them and I may make use of them in the future.

Comment: have you tried http://crscardellino.me/SBWCE/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use webscraping to find a list of synonyms from an online dictionary:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
data = str(urllib.urlopen('https://educalingo.com/en/dic-es/{}'.format('contador')).read())
final_results = re.findall('\w+', [i.text for i in soup(data, 'lxml').find_all('div', {"class":'contenido_sinonimos_antonimos'})][0])
```

Output:

```
[u'cajero', u'contable', u'cuentarrevoluciones', u'electr', u'metro', u'interventor', u'medidor', u'tax', u'metro', u'tesorero', u'volt', u'metro']
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if I would have to resort to do webscraping, but this certainly solves my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ManuelAntonioSanchez Glad to help!